# Case Insensitive Routing in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, router

I've written this in the CodeIgniter's routers.

```
$route['companyname'] = "/profile/1";
```

This is working fine but when I type "CompanyName" into the URL then it doesn't work. This is because upper case characters.

I want to make this routing case insensitive. Please suggest the best way.

Answer (score 23):

Just add expression "**(?i)**"

Here example: 
`$route['(?i)companyname'] = "/profile/1";`

Comment: here, showed url is user typed url.How can I show correct url with case sensitivity.But it should be case Insensitive routing.

Answer (score 4):

If you want case-insensitive routing for all routes, you just need to extend CI_Router class, then modify _parse_routes() method like this:

```
public function _parse_routes()
{
    foreach ($this->uri->segments as &$segment)
    {
        $segment = strtolower($segment);
    }

    return parent::_parse_routes();
}
```

It will be cleaner than editing the CI_URI class itself. :)

Comment: I needed to be able to control the casing of the url so that the linux host I'm using would be able to find the file. +1 for your fine grained control insights.

Comment: Dear @Kevin where to place the extended controller.Kindly guide.

Answer (score 2):

**IN Directory** system/core/uri.php

search about

> $this->_parse_request_uri()

you will find 2 replace them with

> strtolower($this->_parse_request_uri())

Answer (score 1):

Use hooks:

Create application/hooks/LowerUrl.php

```
class LowerUrl {
    public function run() {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
```

Add to application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['pre_system'] = array(
    'class'    => 'LowerUrl',
    'function' => 'run',
    'filename' => 'LowerUrl.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, well, an dirty but straight to the point way would be to make a small hack to the core Uri class. Open the `uri.php` file inside `system/core/` , scroll to line 269 where you have the method `_explode_segments()` and make them lowercase. Bad method, but should work.

```
function _explode_segments()
{
    foreach (explode("/", preg_replace("|/*(.+?)/*$|", "\\1", $this->uri_string)) as $val)
    {
        // Filter segments for security
        $val = trim($this->_filter_uri($val));

        if ($val != '')
        {
                    // $this->segments[] = $val;  // <--- ORIGINAL
            $this->segments[] = strtolower($val);   // <--- CHANGED
        }
    }
}
```

Just consider that if you upgrade your install this changes will be overwritten, but they're so small anyway. Alternatively, you might go for a pre_system hook, but I think it would be much more difficult

Also, in routes you should not use leading or trailing slashes, so it must be

```
$route['companyname'] = "profile/1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [strtolower](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) in your [_remap](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) function. It isn't sure that works, it was just an idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of is to enforce lowercase urls with mod_rewrite (if you're using apache...)

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Source:
http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

Use Router:

```
$urix = substr(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 1);

$route["(?i)$urix"] = $urix;
```

Solution for all Case Insensitive Routings..