# URL routing in CodeIgniter with capitalized controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Controller `Mycontroller.php`, `class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller` and I want to route the index function to take an argument, so I routed it like this in `config/routes.php` : `$route['Mycontroller/(:any)'] = 'Mycontroller/index/$1';`

Everything is fine till I change the case of any character in the controller name in the url.

Example : `http:/localhost/mysite/Mycontroller/argument`

this works but:

`http:/localhost/mysite/mycontroller/argument` doesn't.

Notice how I have changed the case of **M** in the controller name `Mycontroller` now this shows me 404 error and this happens with all the characters of the controller name, if I keep it exactly like in class declaration it works, otherwise it's 404 error.

What can I do to make it work with any combination of upper and lower cases?

P.S. The problem is only with re routed controllers.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161596/case-insensitive-routing-in-codeigniter) solution.