# Unable to load the requested file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Everything is working fine on my Localhost(Xampp) but when i upload the same code on Server(**cPanel**) then it is giving me error **Unable to Load the Requested File**

**Controller:**

```
class Industries extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   public function view_industry($id) {

     $data['view_industry'] = $this->Industry_model->view_industry($id);    
     $data['main_view']  = "Industries/view_industry";
     $this->load->view('templates/main', $data);
   }
}
```

**Route:**

```
$route['view_industry'] = "Industries/view_industry";
```

**View :**

[image]

What could be the reason??? because the same code is working absolutely fine on **LOCALHOST**.

Comment: Case could be the reason: `Industries` != `industries`

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161596/case-insensitive-routing-in-codeigniter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks Bro! that was the issue. Great Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the CASE was the issue.

For example **Industries != industries**

Thanks Guys.